# Como gerar um gráfico com X e Y distintos com o módulo matplotlib em Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

O objetivo seria gerar um gráfico de barras onde o eixo Y vai de 0 a 10(de modo fixo), e o usuário iria informar o valor máximo de X (sendo o eixo X constituído de 1 até o valor informado).

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi a sua duvida de maneira correta, mas da uma olhada nessa solução que criei o valor de Y está fixo de 0 ate 10 e o de X está variável conforme o que o usuário digitar.

Obs: Os valores de X são armazenados em uma lista para facilitar a leitura.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista = []

for i in range(11):
    num = float(input('Digite a posição {}: '.format(i)))
    lista.append(num)

y = range(0,11)
x = lista
plt.ylabel(u'Eixo Y')
plt.xlabel(u'Eixo X')
plt.grid(True)
plt.bar(x, y)

plt.show()
```